# MVC How to hit the controller method when Partial view (create) submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Create click (2nd Partial view) is not hit into action controller. I have used two partial view. I tried the below steps. please see the attached screen shot

1. While clicking Add button (Index), Dropdown Selected value is added into partial view(1st partial view)
2. On Click Edit, another partial view(2nd) is loaded into div.
3. 2'nd PV (Create) click, i'm planning to validate model(SubmitReview), generate xml and update to previous partial view, but this is not happening. please see the below code and suggest me how to achieve?

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var DBQList = DBActivity.Getdbqlist();
    DBQModel viewmodel = new DBQModel();
    var DBQSelectList = new SelectList(DBQList, "DBQ_ID", "DBQ_Name", "IsSelected");
    viewmodel.selectList = DBQSelectList;
    Session["Session_DBQModel"] = viewmodel;
    return View(viewmodel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DBQModel dbqModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //
    }
    var mdl = (DBQModel)Session["Session_DBQModel"];
    var selectedvalue = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["SelectedId"].ToString());
    var rows = DBActivity.Getdbqlist().FirstOrDefault(x => x.DBQ_ID == selectedvalue);
    if (rows != null)
    {
        DBQTable tbl = new DBQTable();
        tbl.DBQ_ID = rows.DBQ_ID;
        tbl.DBQ_Name = rows.DBQ_Name;
        tbl.DBQ_Desc = rows.DBQ_Desc;
        tbl.VAFormNo = rows.VAFormNo;
        mdl.dbqTable.Add(tbl);
    }
    Session["Session_DBQModel"] = mdl;
    return View(mdl);
}


public PartialViewResult LoadDBQ(int id)
{
    if (id==1)
    {
        EatingDisorder eatingDisorder = new EatingDisorder();
        return PartialView("_EatingDisorderPV", eatingDisorder);
    }
    return PartialView("_DefaultPV");
}

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitReview(EatingDisorder _model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                throw new Exception("Please correct the following errors: " + Environment.NewLine + messages);
            }

            if (_model.s1_Bulima)
            {
                if ((_model.s1_Bulima_Date != null) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_model.s1_Bulima_ICD)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_model.s1_Bulima_Name)))
                {
                    //ok
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("s1_Bulima_Date", "s1_Bulima_Date is required.");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("s1_Bulima_ICD", "s1_Bulima_ICD is required.");
                    ModelState.AddModelError("s1_Bulima_Name", "s1_Bulima_Name is required.");
                }
            }

            //save to db
            //return Json(new { Result = "OK" });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }
        return PartialView("_EatingDisorderPV", _model);
    }
```

Iindex.cshtml

```cs
@model WebApplication1.Models.DBQModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SelectedId, Model.selectList, "Please select dbq", new { @class = "from-control col-md-4" })
    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />

    @Html.Partial("_DBQGridPV", Model.dbqTable)

    <div id="DBQHolder"></div>
}
```

_DBQGridPV.cshtml

```cs
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.DBQTable>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DBQ_ID)</th>
        .....
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DBQ_ID)</td>
            .....
            <td>
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "LoadDBQ", new { id = item.DBQ_ID }, 
                    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "DBQHolder", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })|
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteDBQ", new { id = item.DBQ_ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

_EatingDisorderPV.cshtml

```cs
@model WebApplication1.Models.EatingDisorder
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    .....
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

[image]

Comment: The first problem you have is that your generating nested forms which is invalid html and not supported.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I have removed Form tag from EatingDisorderPV.cshml (partial view). Now the whole page (Index.cshtml) have one form tag, Even though is not working..

Comment: If you have done that, everyting will post back to the `public ActionResult Index(DBQModel dbqModel)` method. But I suspect you want your partial to post back to the `public JsonResult SubmitReview(EatingDisorder _model)`? If that is the case, then you still need the `<form>` tag in the partial, but move the partial to below the first `<form>` (so they are not nested). But then that means your `Index()` POST method does not really make sense so I'm not really sure from your code what your trying to do

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you are right i want to postback SubmitReview. so that i moved the DBQHolder is outside of index.cshtml. This is working fine. Suppose if any validation fails, i added ModelState.AddModelError and return partial view with model, but this model message is not displayed also main index page is gone. why? please the modified SubmitReview code.

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page, then you need to use ajax to submit the form, and if you return a partial with validation errors, then replace the existing partial with the returned one. But why are you not using validation attributes (e.g. the `[Required]` attribute) on your properties and using client side validation?